# Rewrite login_check functionality in Symfony

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

How do I add an extra check to the default Symfony login_check? Most documentation is about how to customize the login form, but in this case I only want to add an extra check whether a user has the the `status` active.

I assume that I have to redirect the route `pattern:  /login_check` to my own security check, but what should this function look like?  It seems I can't find any documentation on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use built in AdvancedUserInterface (recommended) http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#forbid-non-active-users or create custom Entity Provider http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#authenticating-someone-with-a-custom-entity-provider

Comment: thanks this indeed seems a solution. The thing is if i implement the AdvanceUserInterface i get an error on the UserInterface::equals implementation. Fatal error: Declaration of Paston\VerBundle\Entity\User::equals() must be compatible with that of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::equals() in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\src\Paston\VerBundle\Entity\User.php on line 14"

Comment: fixed! Had to import both UserInterface as AdvancedUserInterface

Answer (score 0):

See Forbid Non-Active Users here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html  I followed the example and found it quick and easy.